# Apk Installation to Emulator

Tags: android, sdk

I am using Android **SDK 24.3.3**

Now tried installing an apk file to Emulator
It is saying that **"INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK"**

Tried again by changing the minSdkversion and target sdkversion in Manifest file as 24 but of no use.
Can any one of U plz. suggest ....
Many Many Thanks in adv.,

Comment: Could you please specify the android version your emulator is running on and minimum sdk version of your application

Comment: This means the version of android of your avd is older than the version being used to compile the code

Answer (score 0):

minSdkversion must be less or equal to that of device or emulatoryou want to install in.